# c++ vector segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run my c++ program on an amazon linux ec2 instance and getting a segmentation fault in a piece of code that runs fine on MacOS and Ubuntu.  The code excerpt is this

```
    vector<unsigned char> header(8);
    bool bool_byte[8];
    unsigned char seg_byte;
    int byte_num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        bool_byte[i] = snb[i];
        if(i % 8 == 7) {
            seg_byte = to_byte(bool_byte);
            byte_num = (i + 1)/8;
            cout << "byte_num minus one is " << to_string(byte_num - 1) << endl;
            cout << "vector size " << to_string(header.size()) << endl;
            header[byte_num - 1] = seg_byte;
        }
    }
```

I'm converting a 32 bit boolean array to 4 bytes of type unsigned char.  `seg_byte` here may be '\0', but even if I replace `seg_byte` with 'a', or use `header.reserve(8)` and use `push_back` instead of an array index I still get the segmentation fault.  I've also tried using `vector<char>` and casting to `char` and still get the segmentation fault.  The `cout` statements print this.

```
byte_num minus one is 0
vector size 8
byte_num minus one is 1
vector size 139991841770280
Segmentation fault
```

If I write a small `test.cpp` file that only runs a for loop filling a `vector<unsigned char>` I don't get any errors.

Comment: `bool_byte[i] = snb[i];` What happens at this line when `i` becomes larger than 7? (since your loop goes to 31)

Comment: Thank you so much, silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

> getting a segmentation fault in a piece of code that runs fine on MacOS and Ubuntu

If you build your program with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (which you should get into the habit of doing *all the time*), it will tell you *right away* about buffer overflows.

Building with Address Sanitizer is very easy:

```
g++ -fsanitize=address -g test.cpp
```